# Progressbar twitter bootstrap validate input form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've made this code but it happens each time you change the input.

```
    var width =+ 0;
    $("#Email").blur(function()          //whenever you click off an input element
        {    
            if( !$(this).val() ) {                   //if it is blank. 
                animateBar(width-=25); 
            } else {
                animateBar(width+=25);
            }
        });
    function animateBar(percentage)
        {
            $('#bar').animate({width: percentage+"%"}, 150);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
var width =+ 0;
$("#Email").focusout(function()          //whenever you click off an input element
    {    
        if( !$(this).val() ) {                   //if it is blank. 
            animateBar(width-=25); 
        } else {
            animateBar(width+=25);
        }
    });
function animateBar(percentage)
    {
        $('#bar').animate({width: percentage+"%"}, 150);
    }
```

here you have the documentation for the event you are looking for
http://api.jquery.com/focusout/